# why so many "duplicated" (i386 + x86_64) packages installed?

Tags: 11.10, multiarch

I did a fresh install of a 64bit laptop (where previously i had ubuntu 10.04 64bit) I now notice that everytime i install a package from the reppos, i get lots of duplicate libs both in 32bit and 64bit, why?

I only have the official ubuntu reppos and installed OpenShot video editor and Flash and a few other things like CompizConfig Settings Manager and Gnome Tweak Tool...

I now magically have 122 duplicated libs in 2 different architectures, why?

`dpkg -l|grep ":i386"|wc -l`

If i inspect this list i find both 64bit and 32bit in my system... This is really a waste of space and then which one is used by the apps? 32 or 64?

It is really confusing...

Comment: If you install Wine, it installs ia32-libs which installs lots of :i386 packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because flashplugin-installer:amd64 depends flashplugin-downloader:i386. And for working multiarch needs more i386 packages.

Just remove flashplugin-installer, flashplugin-downloader:i386 and other i386 packages and install adobe-flashplugin:amd64.

But if you want install skype there is only i386 package in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot now. And it depends many i386 packages.

Answer (score 1):

I would say those are dependencies for some 32bit tools you are using. Its not a waste of space because they are needed, not everything will work with 64bit so those packages are need to make sure all runs smoothly.